# Formatting text using php

Tags: php

I want to format the text that will be inserted into a text area.

Text will have a similar structure (I noted * - * blank lines.):

```
Phone
*-*
02.03.2007 My phone is excellent.
*-*
*-*
Phone
02.06.2007 I want new phone.
....
```

How do I delete one blank line as in the example below?

```
Phone
02.03.2007 My phone is excellent.

Phone
02.06.2007 I want new phone.
```

The code that I have now yet do nothing

```
    <?php


        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $text = $_POST["text"];
            $text = .....
         }
    ?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

<input style="display:block;" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="45" rows="700">
</textarea>


<textarea name="result" id="result" cols="45" rows="700">
<?php echo $text; ?>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Now there are already 4 questions with pretty much the same code!

Comment: So can you please tell me the differences between: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29488383/3933332 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/29488383/3933332 these other two's ?

Answer (score 0):

Try preg_replace php function

```
<textarea name="result" id="result" cols="45" rows="700">
    <?php echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $text); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Delete all spaces. Not just one blank line.

Comment: Yeah can user function trim() to help remove that

Comment: try this one   <?php echo trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $text)); ?>
@John

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why the other answers use regular expressions for this case, `str_replace` will work just fine:

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n", $text);
```

Windows and Unix newlines are different, windows has the extra carriage return(`\r`). You might also want to have a look at the PHP constant `PHP_EOL`.